# filter out certain processes and/or pids in ftrace?

Tags: linux, process, system-calls, tracing, ftrace

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this the right way (and please correct me if I'm wrong), but the following is my understanding of ftrace.

In /sys/kernel/debug/tracing, there are the following files:

> set_ftrace_filter

which will only trace the functions listed inside,

> set_ftrace_notrace

which will only trace the functions NOT listed inside, and

> set_ftrace_pid

which will only trace the processes with the pid inside.

**My question is:** is there a way to configure it so that ftrace will only trace processes that DO NOT have a certain pid (or process name)?

Analogy:

set_ftrace_filter : set_ftrace_notrace :: set_ftrace_pid : **x**

Does **x** exist, and if so, how do I use it?

For instance, if I wanted to trace all processes except the one with pid 48, is there some way to put something meaning **not 48** into set_ftrace_pid?

I've been reading the documentation and searching the web, but I can't find either the way to achieve this or whether this is possible.

**Why I'm doing this:** I have a program that's tracing kernel-level system calls, but I want to write the program's pid (and the pids of its children, if necessary later) to a filter so that they aren't included with the trace data.  When reading the trace, I could check the pid as I read each trace record and decide whether to use that record or not, but I would prefer not to add this overhead for every record that is read if there's a way to avoid it.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I was describing, but it was a bit counter-intuitive, so I'm posting the answer here for people who might hit this page when searching (**tl:dr;** at bottom).  **As far as I know,** there is no blanket way to just filter out processes with a certain PID from ftrace as easily as it is to tell it to ONLY consider processes with a certain PID, but in my case, I only care about raw system calls (sys_enter) and I found out how to eliminate records with certain PIDs from being included for those and this is how:

The ftrace directory is:

> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/

Inside, there is a directory called "**events**."  From here, you can see all the things that ftrace can trace, but for my case, I go into "**raw_syscalls**."

Within **raw_syscalls**," the two subdirectories are **sys_enter** and **sys_exit**.

Within sys_enter (and sys_exit, for that matter), there are the following files:

> enable
>
> filter
>
> format
>
> id
>
> trigger

"**filter**" is the one we care most about right now, but **format** has useful information regarding the fields of an entry produced by ftrace when sys_enter is enabled:

```
name: sys_enter
ID: 17
format:
    field:unsigned short common_type;   offset:0;   size:2; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_flags;   offset:2;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;   offset:3;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:int common_pid;   offset:4;   size:4; signed:1;

    field:long id;  offset:8;   size:8; signed:1;
    field:unsigned long args[6];    offset:16;  size:48;    signed:0;
```

Here, we care about **common_pid**.

If you want your trace to omit records from a process with PID **n**, you would edit

> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls/sys_enter/filter

To read:

```
common_pid != n
```

If the program you're trying to ignore while tracing has multiple threads or multiple processes, you just use the && operator.  Say you want to omit processes with PIDs **n**, **o**, and **p**, you would edit the file so that it reads:

```
common_pid != n && common_pid != o && common_pid != p
```

To clear a filter, you just write "**0**" to the file:

echo "0" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls/sys_enter/filter

...would do the trick.

**enable** has to contain "**1**" for the event you're tracing as well as **tracing_on** in the ftrace directory.  Writing in **0** turns tracing of that event (or all tracing in the case of **tracing_on**) off.

Writing to these files requires root permissions.

That's about all I can think of.  Thanks to anyone who read/voted on this and I hope my answer helps someone.  If anyone knows a way that makes the way I did it look stupid, feel free to call me out.

**tl;dr:** to filter out records from process 48, write:

```
common_pid != 48
```

...to

> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls/sys_enter/filter

Filter multiple PIDs (eg. 48, 49, 53, 58) by writing this instead:

```
common_pid != 48 && common_pid != 49 && common_pid != 53 && common_pid !=58
```

Replace "events/raw_syscalls/sys_enter" with your desired event and replace my numbers with whatever PIDs you want to ignore.